# Circular Type Constraints

Tags: .net, generics, f#

I have two interfaces:
`IState` and `IAction`.
A State has a method: GetActions - which returns a collection of IActions.
A Action has a method: Apply - which acts on a State, to return a new State.

IState takes a type parameter to control what sort of actions it returns with get actions,
IAction takes a type parameter to control what sort of states it can act on.
(By sort, i ment implementation).
I want to be able to garentee that a State only return actions that can act on a state of that same type.

```
type IAction<'S when 'S:>IState> =
    abstract member Apply : 'S->'S

and IState<'A when 'A:>IAction<'S when 'S:> typeof(this)>> = 
    abstract member GetActions : seq<'A>
```

but obviously `typeof(this)` is not a thing.
How can I have a type constraint making sure my type paramerer is of type equal to the type I am defining?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A solution to avoid getting into the problem in the first place

Not a direct answer to your question, but it should solve your original problem:

```
type StateMachine<'State, 'Action> =
    interface
        abstract Apply : 'State * 'Action -> 'State
        abstract GetActions : 'State -> 'Action seq
    end
```

This way of approaching the problem is inspired by [ML's module system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML#Module_system)

### An uglier solution

If you really want to go for the two tightly coupled interfaces, you could go that way:

```
type IState<'Action, 'State when 'Action :> IAction<'State, 'Action> and 'State :> IState<'Action, 'State>> =
    interface
        abstract GetActions : unit -> 'Action seq
    end

and IAction<'State, 'Action when 'Action :> IAction<'State, 'Action> and 'State :> IState<'Action, 'State>> =
    interface
        abstract Apply : 'State -> 'State
    end

// Some stupid types to illustrate how to implement the interfaces
type State() =
    interface IState<Action, State> with
        member this.GetActions() = Seq.empty

and Action() =
    interface IAction<State, Action> with
        member this.Apply s = s
```

I hope people won't start using the second solution and make a design pattern named after me out of it :)

Comment: "I hope people won't start using the second solution and make a design pattern named after me out of it" LOL.  Like having a disease named after you.